# Simple moving average - losing data points

Tags: moving-average

Let's say I have data for 6 days. The values for these days are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

So if I want to calculate a 2-day moving average of these data points, I'll get 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, and 5.5.

This means that I'm left with only 5 data points of the moving average, compared to 6 data points of the original data. It also means that if I want to plot the two, the line of the moving average will be shorter.

First, am I right, or am I missing something?

Second, is there anything to do about it? like maybe giving the last data point its original value (and not an average)?

Thanks!